Is there a method like elementFromPoint that is relative to an offsetParent rather than viewport?
This example code used elementFromPoint to illustrate the kind of task I'd like to perform but the question is rather than being confined to viewport coordinates and that which is visible, is there a way to get the element at a particular offest within scrl_can that is not currently displayed in the container, apart from iterating through all the child elements and testing for one for which offset is between (offsetTop, offsetTop + offsetHeight)? Is there a native method that will return similar to elementFromPoint but relative to another element?
For example, suppose the height or every tr is not guaranteed to be the same, and I want to know which tr is at an offset of 400px when the scrl_can scrollTop is zero such that that tr is not visible.
Thank you.


var 
   table = document.querySelector("TABLE"),
   scrl_can = table.parentNode,
   input = scrl_can.previousElementSibling,
   button = input.previousElementSibling,
   tbody = document.createElement("TBODY"),
   tr, 
   td =[],
   gBCR = scrl_can.getBoundingClientRect()
;
for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++ ) {
  tr = document.createElement("TR")
  tr.append(
      td[0] = document.createElement("TD"),
      td[1] = document.createElement("TD"),
      td[2] = document.createElement("TD")
  );
  td[0].textContent = i + 1
  td[1].textContent = String.fromCharCode(65+i);
  td[2].textContent = String.fromCharCode(97+i);
  tbody.append(tr);
}
table.append(tbody);



function GetTopRow() {
  input.value = document.elementFromPoint(gBCR.left+3,gBCR.top+3).closest('tr').firstElementChild.textContent;
}  

button.addEventListener( 'click', GetTopRow );
.scrl_can {
  height: 150px;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input { 
  width: 25px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
<button>Get Top Row</button><input type="text">
<div class="scrl_can">
  <table></table>
</div>




The alternatives you can explore are Virtual Scrolling , Lazy Loading or using Intersection Observer API. Intersection Observer API to observe when elements come into the viewport and trigger actions accordingly. However, this wouldn't directly solve your problem but might help in optimizing rendering.
